# New WP_Query loop in admin causes problems

Tags: wp-query, loop, metabox, post-meta

I am working on a project where I have a custom post type 'companies' and on this edit page in the Wordpress admin I have some custom made meta boxes, for saving company information, opening hours, pictures etc etc.

Since yesterday I added a meta box for Leads to show the posts in the custom post type "leads" of this companies. To show these posts I use a new WP_Query. The leads posts are displayed correctly, but the meta data from my opening hours and pictures are gone now.

Does anyone know what I need to change to this loop to use it in a Wordpress admin. (I also tried  `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end op the loop).

I register the meta boxes first off course and these are the functions in it.

```
// Company Leads
function stn_inner_company_leads( $post ){

    $args = array( 
        'post_type'     => 'leads',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'page_id',
                'value' => $post->ID,
            )
        ),
    );

    $leads = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $leads->have_posts() ) {
        $counter = 0;
        echo '<table id="lead_table" width="100%">';
        echo '<tbody>';
        while ( $leads->have_posts() ) { $leads->the_post();
            $counter++;

            $output  = '<tr>';
            $output .= '<td># ' . $counter . '</td>';
            $output .= '<td><a href="' . get_edit_post_link() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></td>';
            $output .= '<td>' . get_the_date( 'l, F j, Y g:i a' ) . '</td>';
            $output .= '</tr>';
            echo $output;
        }
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';

    } else {
        _e( 'This company has no leads.' );
    }
    wp_reset_query();

}
```

This is my function for opening hours:

```
// Opening hours        
function stn_inner_opening_hours( $post ) {

    global $company;

    echo '<div class="stn_inner_box">';
    echo '<fieldset>';

    foreach ( $company['opening_hours'] as $key => $value) {

        $value[1] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key . '_is_open', true );
        $value[2] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key . '_open', true );
        $value[3] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key . '_closed', true );

        $output = '<ul class="time_row">';

        $output .= '<label for="company_' . $key . '">';
        $output .= __( $value[0] ) . ':';
        $output .= '</label>';

        $output .= '<li><select name="company_' . $key . '_is_open' . '">';
        $output .= '<option ' . ( $value[1] == 'open' ? 'selected' : '' ) . ' value="open">' . __( 'Open' ) . '</option>';
        $output .= '<option ' . ( $value[1] == 'closed' ? 'selected' : '' ) . ' value="closed">' . __( 'Closed' ) . '</option>';
        $output .= '</select></li>';

        $output .= '<li>' . __( 'From' ) . ':</li>';
        $output .= '<li><select name="company_' . $key . '_open' . '">';
        for ( $n = strtotime("00:00"), $e = strtotime("23:30"); $n <= $e; $n += 1800 ) {
            $this_time = date("H:i", $n);
            $output .= '<option ' . ( $value[2] == $this_time ? 'selected' : '' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $this_time ) . '" >' . $this_time . '</option>'; 
        }
        $output .= '</select></li>';

        $output .= '<li>' . __( 'Till' ) . ':</li>';
        $output .= '<li><select name="company_' . $key . '_closed' . '">';
        for ( $n = strtotime("00:00"), $e = strtotime("23:30"); $n <= $e; $n += 1800 ) {
            $this_time = date("H:i",$n);
            $output .= '<option ' . ( $value[3] == $this_time ? 'selected' : '' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $this_time ) . '" >' . $this_time . '</option>'; 
        }
        $output .= '</select></li>';

        $output .= '</ul>';

        echo $output;

    }

    echo '</fieldset>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

var_dump($post); gives me the following result:

```
object(WP_Post)#352 (24) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(5) "44625"
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-03-31 06:54:14"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2014-03-31 06:54:14"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(12) "Test salon 2"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(12) "test-salon-2"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2014-03-31 06:56:55"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2014-03-31 06:56:55"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["guid"]=>
  string(59) "http://www.mywebsite.com/?post_type=companies&amp;p=44625"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(9) "companies"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(4) "edit"
}
```

Comment: What is `var_dump($post);` inside the ` stn_inner_opening_hours()` function? How is this code used?

Comment: Try taking out wp_reset_query(); in the content function, you don't need since you're not modifying the main query.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I have added the output of var_dump($post); to my question.

Comment: I have removed `wp_reset_query();` and my fields are getting saved now, but I don't know if this is because of removing this function, because it looks like if I switch the meta boxes in my admin this would make the difference. And if I place it back I still got the same result now..